# Copy file into another folder with django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, image-upload, django-file-upload

I need to upload profile images into diferent folders in Django. So, I have a folder for each account, and the profile image have to go to the specific folder. How can I do that?

Here is my **uploadprofile.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'uploadimage' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And here is my view in **views.py**

```
def uploadimage(request):
    img = request.FILES['avatar'] #Here I get the file name, THIS WORKS

    #Here is where I create the folder to the specified profile using the user id, THIS WORKS TOO
    if not os.path.exists('static/profile/' + str(request.session['user_id'])):
        os.mkdir('static/profile/' + str(request.session['user_id']))


    #Here is where I create the name of the path to save as a VARCHAR field, THIS WORKS TOO
    avatar = "../../static/profile/" + str(request.session['user_id']) + "/" + str(img)

    #THEN I HAVE TO COPY THE FILE IN img TO THE CREATED FOLDER

    return redirect(request, 'myapp/upload.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) what you get when you do `img = request.FILES['avatar']` is a *file descriptor* that points to an open file with your image.

Then you should to dump the contents in your actual `avatar` path, right?

```
#Here is where I create the name of the path to save as a VARCHAR field, THIS WORKS TOO
avatar = "../../static/profile/" + str(request.session['user_id']) + "/" + str(img)
# # # # # 
with open(avatar, 'wb') as actual_file:
    actual_file.write(img.read())
# # # # #    
return redirect(request, 'myapp/upload.html')
```

Beware: the code is untested.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a callable to `upload_to`. Basically, what it means is whatever value that callable returns, the image will be uploaded in that path.

Example:

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" % (instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel:
    user = ...
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

---

There's more information in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) and an example too, though similar to what I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage



def uploadimage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['avatar']:
        img = request.FILES['avatar']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        #To copy image to the base folder 
        #filename = fs.save(img.name, img)     

        #To save in a specified folder
        filename = fs.save('static/profile/'+img.name, img)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)                 #To get the file`s url
        return render(request, 'myapp/upload.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
     return render(request, 'myapp/upload.html')
```